# Parse and filter javascript array

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, json.net

Our legacy code uses `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter` to produce a javascript array like:

```
[["1","zxc"],["2","fifa"],["3","fgh"]].
```

I wonder if Newtonsoft.Json provides counterparts to help filter out or get specific elements, such as `["3","fgh"]`.

Comment: I'm sorta confused.  If you're trying to get ["3", "fgh"] with javascript, you can simply eval() into an array and get the 2nd element...  If you're using C#, of course, its a totally different story.  However, if you were really desperate, you could us CodeDom.Compiler... and replace "[" and "]"s with "{" and "}"s respectively... and get the resulting array... hehe

Comment: Are you trying to deserialize it? The Newtonsoft namespace means that you're using JSON.NET.

Comment: I'd like to know if I can retrieve ["3","fgh"] based on a input like fgh.

Answer (score 2):

The serializer produces JSON from an array you are supplying as argument. Filter the array before passing it to the serializer.